# Does Facebook Dev have an official Twitter feed for API updates, alerts, etc

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Facebook has committed to a 90 day break warning, but you have to actively follow their blog or rss to stay on top of things. I know that this new fangled thing called twitter would be a much better way to allow people to subscribe to such alerts.  I use it with Assembla, Zend, Doctrine, etc... and it's much more efficient and timely than having to spend time trolling through all their idiosyncratic  reporting blogs or forum posts.

Does the facebook already have a twitter feed specifically for this?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://twitter.com/#!/fbplatform is about as close of a resource that I think you'll find.

Watching the platform page and blog on FB is still probably your best way of keeping up with what's going on.